# How to remove the shadow from a librarystack

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, shadow, pixelsense

I'm currently in a project where I need a LibraryStack with no visuals at all, so it would just show the content. If I just remove the background a shadow stays in view which I cant seem to remove...

[librarystack with no background http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/6778/librarystack.jpg](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/6778/librarystack.jpg)

This code looks like:

```
<s:LibraryStack Background="Transparent">
    <s:LibraryStackItem Background="AliceBlue"/>
    <s:LibraryStackItem Background="Bisque"/>
    <s:LibraryStackItem Background="Salmon"/>
</s:LibraryStack>
```

This stack is just for explaining purposes, the actual stack is added in the code behind in c#. So preferably any answers that would be usefull to add in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to re-template the control. For example:

```
<s:LibraryStack>
  <s:LibraryStack.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type s:LibraryStack}">
      <Grid>
        <ItemsPresenter/>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </s:LibraryStack.Template>
  <s:LibraryStackItem Background="AliceBlue"/>
  <s:LibraryStackItem Background="Bisque"/>
  <s:LibraryStackItem Background="Salmon"/>
</s:LibraryStack>
```